# UndoableEditListener never called in JTextPane/JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jtextpane, undo-redo

I am trying to attach an `UndoableEditListener` to a `JTextPane` or `JTextArea` that queues up edits into an `UndoManager`.

```
textPane.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(new UndoableEditListener() {
    @Override
    public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent event) {
        undoQueue.addEdit(event.getEdit());
    }
});
```

But `undoableEditHappened` is never called when I type "aaa" in the text window.

Thinking it's Java's fault, not mine, I crack `AbstractDocument.class` open with Eclipse debugger to watch the event trigger. It has a private `listeners` array. `AbstractDocument` stores all its listeners in odd indices in the `listeners` array, with the listeners' type Class<>'s in the even indices.

```
protected void fireUndoableEditUpdate(UndoableEditEvent e) {
    // Guaranteed to return a non-null array
    Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
    // Process the listeners last to first, notifying
    // those that are interested in this event
    for (int i = listeners.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
        if (listeners[i] == UndoableEditListener.class) {
            // Lazily create the event:
            // if (e == null)
            // e = new ListSelectionEvent(this, firstIndex, lastIndex);
            ((UndoableEditListener) listeners[i + 1]).undoableEditHappened(e);
        }
    }
}
```

See the line `if (listeners[i] == UndoableEditListener.class)`? When I add the undo change listener, the debugger shows `listeners` containing my listener, along with `UndoableEditListener.class` in the index before it. But, when the debugger comes to that if-statement, all the even indices in the array `listeners` show as `DocumentListener.class` in the debugger. Consequently, the if-statement is always `false` and the listener never called.

What the heck? Is this a Java 8 bug? Or am I missing a step the examples forgot to mention?

Comment: Have you tried the demo code found in the [Implementing Undo/Redo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#undo) section of the Swing tutorial? The code works fine for me using JDK7 on Windows 7.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: I started over with the demo code, and sure enough it worked. Thanks for that suggestion. It led me to notice I had customized my JTextPane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the `JTextPane`.  I was overriding its `setText` method to force it to call `read`, the alternative to `setText` that normalizes all kinds of newline while remembering them. But `JTextPane.read` appears to not trigger an `UndoableEditEvent` on the document.

If I leave `setText` alone, then `UndoManager.undo` works.